# how to use dynamic CRM on premise api in php to create lead

Tags: php, rest, api, curl, soap

I wanted to create leads in dynamic CRM using api in php. Currently I am using rest api, using curl but it is throwing an error-

> HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied Status: 401NULL
>   string(371) "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Cache-Control: private
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked...

Please someone help me.

This is my code:

```
    $ZDURL= "https://[org]/api/data/v8.1/accounts";

    $data =curlWrap($ZDURL); 
    var_dump($data);

    function curlWrap($ZDURL)
    {    
        $ch = curl_init();  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username:password');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ZDURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if( $result === false) 
    {echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch); }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    $status = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
    echo "Status: ".$status;
    curl_close($ch);
    $decoded = json_decode($output);
    return $decoded;
}
```

Comment: Well that error is clearly telling you that your curl request was rejected because you're not logged in. But I can only assume because you haven't provided a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. Does that help?

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Silly question from me, but have you actually replace `'username:password'` with your real username and password in your actual code?

Comment: Just checking, you'll be surprised how often that can be the case. Are you connecting to an on-premise instance or an online? What type of authentication is enabled, e.g. is it ADFS?

Comment: on-premise. authentication not sure, NTLM I think.

Comment: not using ADFS authentication

Comment: Please refer to this link, [Answer on this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215067/trying-to-create-lead-in-dynamic-crm-using-api-in-php?noredirect=1#comment69630624_41215067)