# PHP - How o get access token in dynamic CRM 2016

Tags: php, rest, api, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to get an access token using dynamic crm 2016 on-premise API and create leads further. but not sure how to get it.

I was using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215067/trying-to-create-lead-in-dynamic-crm-using-api-in-php) (in answer) to create leads in dynamic CRM 2015 on-premise using REST API. It was working good.

We have upgraded the dynamic CRM version to 2016. and now this above code not working anymore. Now CRM is using ADFS and IFD.

Can someone please help me. It is giving me 401 error. username and pwd are correct.